# I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord with scope

Tags: activerecord, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scope, i18n-gem

I want to enable users to overwrite custom translations in the locales/YAML-files.
I use the `i18n-active_record` gem by Sven Fuchs which works great to use translations stored in the database.

The problem: Users should only get their own translations, not those of others.

So I added a `user_id` column to the `translations` table. Now I have no idea how to setup a scope for `I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord`.

My `locale.rb` (in config/initializers):

```
require 'i18n/backend/active_record'
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new

I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Memoize)
I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Flatten)
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Memoize)
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Pluralization)

I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(I18n.backend, I18n::Backend::Simple.new)
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

try adding this to an initializer file

ie: added to where you initialize the activerecord backend for i18n

> config/initializers/i18n_backend.rb

```
require 'i18n/backend/active_record'

if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'translations'
  require 'i18n/backend/active_record'
  I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.
  new(I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new, I18n.backend)
end


# OVERRIDING DEFAULT QUERY
module I18n
  module Backend
    class ActiveRecord 
      class Translation < ::ActiveRecord::Base
        class << self
          def locale(locale)
            where(:locale => locale.to_s).where(:field => condition)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this should overrides the default locale method in the i18n-active_record gem